# Consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

conseguem me ajudar com essa consulta?

```
CREATE TABLE Region
(
    idRegion INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,cdRegion VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Store(
    idStore INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,cdStore VARCHAR(50)
    ,dsStore VARCHAR(200)
)


CREATE TABLE StorexRegion
(
    idStore INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Store(idStore)
    ,idRegion INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Region(idRegion)
)

CREATE TABLE Sales(
    idSales INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) 
    ,idStore INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Store(idStore)
    ,idRegion INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Region(idRegion)
    ,vlTotal FLOAT
)
```

#### Usando as tabelas acima, crie uma consulta que vincule uma loja com a região correspondente(s)

Tentei essa consulta, não sei se está correta:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  STORE S 
  INNER JOIN REGION R ON S.IDSTORE = R.IDREGION
```

#### Crie uma consulta que devote a quantidade total de vendas de uma loja por Região

```
SELECT 
  SUM(S.VLTOTAL) 
FROM 
  SALES S 
  INNER JOIN STORE ST ON S.IDSALES = ST.IDSORTE
  INNER JOIN REGION R ON = S.IDSALES = R.IDREGION
GROUP BY R.IDREGION
```

Comment: ajudar a gente consegue, mostre ai o que já fez, coloque o `select` que já tentou

Comment: Tentei essas duas:
1-
SELECT * FROM STORE S INNER JOIN REGION R
ON S.IDSTORE = R.IDREGION

2- 
SELECT SUM(S.VLTOTAL) * FROM SALES S INNER JOIN STORE ST
ON S.IDSALES = ST.IDSORTE
INNER JOIN REGION R
ON = S.IDSALES = R.IDREGION
GROUP BY R.IDREGION

Comment: Coloque um exemplo com registro em http://sqlfiddle.com/ desta forma podemos lhe ajudar mais facilmente

Comment: edite a pergunta e coloque a query lá para ficar melhor de visualizar

Comment: editei a pergunta, desculpas pela forma que fiz aqui..

Comment: @LucasLira editei a pergunta, mas ainda precisamos um exemplo de dados para te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa fazer apenas é cruzar todas as tabelas, e depois trazer os resultados como o solicitado.

Usando as tabelas acima, crie uma consulta que vincule uma loja com a região correspondente(s):

```
Select sxr.idStore, sto.dsStore, sxr.idRegion, reg.cdRegion
FROM StorexRegion sxr
INNER JOIN Store sto
  ON sto.idStore = sxr.idStore
INNER JOIN Region reg
  ON reg.idRegion = sxr.idRegion
```

Crie uma consulta que devote a quantidade total de vendas de uma loja por Região:

```
Select sxr.idStore, sto.dsStore, sxr.idRegion, reg.cdRegion, COUNT(sal.idSales) Qtd_vendas
FROM StorexRegion sxr
INNER JOIN Store sto
  ON sto.idStore = sxr.idStore
INNER JOIN Region reg
  ON reg.idRegion = sxr.idRegion
INNER JOIN Sales sal
  ON sal.idStore = sto.idStore
  AND sal.idRegion = reg.idRegion
GROUP BY sxr.idStore, sto.dsStore, sxr.idRegion, reg.cdRegion
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado..